# synchronized methods executing simulaneously

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, synchronized, java.util.concurrent

As per synchronized keyword, if applied on to the method then it acquires the object lock and multiple methods with same instance would not be able to execute the methods concurrently.

But in the below example, the execution is happening concurrently.
please have a look:-

```java
public class ncuie extends Thread{

    int b;
    ncuie(int a){
        b=a;
    }
    
    public synchronized void abc() throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("thread 1 "+i);
        }
    }
    
    public synchronized void pqr() throws InterruptedException {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("thread 2 "+i);
        }
        
    }
    
    public void run() {
        
        try {
            if(b==5) {
            abc();
            }
            if(b==10) {
            pqr();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t=new ncuie(5);
        Thread t1=new ncuie(10);
        t.start();
        t1.start();
    }
}
```

As per the output, sometimes thread 1 is executed and sometimes thread2.
Ideally only, one thread should have gained the lock and completed it execution, then only the second should have started.

Output:-

```
thread 1 0
thread 1 1
thread 2 0
thread 2 1
thread 2 2
thread 1 2
thread 1 3
thread 1 4
thread 1 5
thread 1 6
thread 1 7
thread 1 8
thread 2 3
thread 2 4
thread 2 5
thread 2 6
thread 1 9
thread 2 7
thread 2 8
thread 2 9
```

Comment: That happens because you make multiple instances of class `ncuie`. Locks are **per object**. The first thread locks on one object, the second one locks on another object.

Comment: Then how shall we create multiple threads with the same instance to achieve proper synchronization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You typically synchronize **on your instance** if some methods change internal state in such a way that other methods operating **on the same instance** would get into trouble. Synchronizing on the current instance (`this`) is what you get by using the `synchronized` keyword on a non-static method, or by writing `synchronized(this) {...}`.

If your methods change state in such a way that even methods operating **on a different instance** of the class get affected, you can synchronize on the class object. You do this by writing `synchronized(MyClass.class) {...}`.

If you have static methods that need synchronization against other static methods of the same class, you can get the synchronization on the class object by using the `synchronized` keyword on the static method.

Be aware that instance-level synchronization and class-level synchronization are completely independent, meaning that, while a class-synchronized method runs, instance-synchronized methods are not blocked.

In your case, you synchronized on the instance, and you have two different instances, so they are not blocking one another.

Answer (score 2):

`synchronized` acquire lock on `this`. You have two instances of your `ncuie` class, so it is perfectly fine to have them both locked simultaneously.

To solve it you need to share some instance between your thread. I suggest to create new `Object` and pass it into constrictor.